# How to use Media Queries in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, media-queries

I have this problem: I'm making header with responsive size, so when the width less than 1199px, user can see hamburger menu. To open/close menu, I'm using React Hooks and it changes display: block / none. But it has to work only when the screen is less than 1199px, but in my case it works every time, and obviously my header has display: none and there's nothing on page (there's only my logo)

**Component's code:**

```
const Header = () => {
    const [navBar, showNavBar] = useState(false)

    const useNavBar = () => {
        showNavBar(!navBar)
    }

    return (
        <header class="header-area main-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="logo-area">
                            <a href='#'><img src={logo} alt="logo"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div onClick={useNavBar} class="custom-navbar">
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="main-menu">
                            <ul style={navBar === true ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'}}> // problem is here
                                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">schedule</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">trainers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">blog</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Blog Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Blog Details</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">pages</a>
                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                        <li><a href="s#">Service</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Elements</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-btn">
                                    <a href="#" class="template-btn">book now</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
     );
}
```

**SASS code:**

```
.main-menu 
    ul 
        float: right
        @include desktop() 
            display: none
            float: left
            position: absolute
            top: 60px
            right: 0
            z-index: 4
            background: $dark
            width: 40%
            padding: 20px 20px 30px
```

PS: I don't want to add all of my CSS code, because it's over 200 strings, just explain me how to change display using media queries in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use inline style. Change *class names* with JavaScript.

Set the `display` in your stylesheet based on the class name and media queries.

```
<ul className={navBar === true ? "foo" : "bar"}>
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand, just don't want to duplicate code.. I guess there are not variants more?